# hive query on hbase external table with STARTROW and STOPROW

Tags: hive, hbase

I've created an external hive table over a hbase table.

hbase shell allows you to do range scans with STARTROW and STOPROW parameters.

How do i run a hive query on this external table using a STARTROW and STOPROW to limit the number of rows scanned in hbase? I've searched hive documentation and can't find any way to set start/stop row or construct where clause which will use start/stop row.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how are build your row but did you have a look to TABLESAMPLE ?

```
SELECT * FROM source TABLESAMPLE(10 ROWS);
```

For example this query will return you the ten first rows of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation. To solve the problem, instead of using STARTROW/ENDROW, I used the 'where' statement in Hive:

```
SELECT * FROM HIVE_HBASE_INTEGRATION_TABLE
    WHERE rowkey >= "Your_startrow_here"
        AND rowkey <= "Your_stoprow_here";
```

This code will get you the same portion from STARTROW/ENDROW.

I would like to use STARTROW/ENDROW in the Hive SERDEPROPERTIES, but couldn't find a way to do it. Hope someone has a better/efficient solution for this.

Comment: Hive doesn't pass this the startRow and stopRow limitation to HBase to the HBase scan it creates. Hive runs a full table scan and then filter the rows.